# php mail not receiving form data

Tags: php, forms, email, post

i'm sending a **email** with **php mail**.
the email is sent normally.

but when a recieved the email the **DATA** from the **FORM** is not recieved.

her is the code :

```html
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="mailcheck.php">
   <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name *</label>
        <input type="text" name="name12" id="name12" class="form-control" required="required" onfocus="showborder('name12')" onblur="hideborder('name12')" style="border: 1px solid #C5CAE9;">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email *</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="required" onfocus="showborder('email')"   onblur="hideborder('email')"
style="border: 1px solid #C5CAE9;">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Envoyer Message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**mailcheck.php**

```js
<?php
try {
$name=$_POST["name12"];
$Email=$_POST["email"];

    $body = "Name: $name \n"; 
    $body .= "Email: $Email \n"; 

    mail("ilyes.bourouba7@gmail.com","new mail",$body); 

//  echo"<script> window.location.replace('contact-us.php?add=ok'); </script>";   
 } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo "cant send email";
 }



?>
```

and her is the email that i recieved

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0BDb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not check to see if a form has been submitted, so it will send email every time you hit the page. Wrap it in an if:

```php
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
try {
$name=$_POST["name12"];
$Email=$_POST["email"];

    $body = "Name: $name \n"; 
    $body .= "Email: $Email \n"; 

    mail("ilyes.bourouba7@gmail.com","new mail",$body); 

//  echo"<script> window.location.replace('contact-us.php?add=ok'); </script>";   
 } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo "cant send email";
 }
}
```